Supplier wants source files....why?
My designer made a label and sent it as a PDF for a supplier to print and then put it on my supplement bottle.  She said she needs the source file because the PDF will be jumbled, but I don't think this is true.  I talked to my designer and she said this is weird and wouldn't know why they can't just use the PDF...  Is there a reason why she needs it?  I'm starting to worry that they may want to steal the label.  Thanks.

It's exceptionally unlikely a label is so earth-shattering original and unique that a packaging company wants to "steal" the label. Trust me they have software jockeys much more experienced than your designer. If they want to, they could recreate your label from scratch. With that posted, it's not "impossible" but the odds are slim. If they inform you there's a problem with the PDF and need native files, it's typically to correct poor construction, which can't be corrected with the PDF.

Generally, a PDF should be enough. You should ask your printer what is wrong with the PDF that was supplied. That's the best way to find out. Anything else would just be guessing.

Steal the label :))) What are you, Microsoft ? Your designer probably delivered the wrong bleed, or crop, or die cut shape, or some wrong size somewhere, and this supplier wants to help you out by making specific adjustments that would specifically work with their machines.

Short answer, the PDF should be sufficient, but printing technicians can receive poorly designed files with a variety of issues that makes it easier to directly ask for the native files, just in case.
First, it should be clear that the PDF file format in itself isn't faulty. Quite the contrary:

it allows you to use any resolution sufficient for industrial needs;
it has layers that can be extracted separately. Worrying about contents that might get "jumbled"? Put them on different layers. Needing to indicate some areas that should undergo a different printing process such as coating? Create a layer with one color to mask the chosen areas, and clarify this with the printer.

However, from the point of view of the printing company, there are many details that can be overlooked by the designer, especially without experience about the printing process. Some examples are the bleeds, spot colors, coatings, pagination... all more or less technical details.
If there is such an issue, the printing company can solve it with its own software; but sometimes the easiest way is to directly use the native file, correct the error there, and re-export. So in the end, this save an amount of time that is precious, given that the company's strategy is to be able to take as many constracts as possible.
Edit: the ability to use layers depend on the specific PDF format, it is not always present.

You assume the PDF was exported/saved to a PDF version that supports layers.. if it's PDFX1a (standard). there may be no layers and all transparency has been flattened... which can't be fixed on their end with just the PDF.

You're right, thanks for the rectification! A few months ago I sent to my printer a cover with coating encoded in a layer using the default PDF file format from InDesign, whence my mistake.
